# Shopify Theme Editing via api

Tags: php, api, shopify, edit, liquid

I am making a Shopify App, i just login via oauth
but the asset api id proving put method with key val api call
where key is having a file name and value is the content of that file.

My concern is that how can we modify the existing liquid file like vqmod by search and replace or search and apned something just before it or after it

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the asset with the API, and then send the modified asset back to Shopify. The API doesn't provide methods for appending to an asset or replacing within an asset.

If you are building a public Shopify app then think about whether your app can use the [ScriptTag API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag) instead. Script tags are less invasive and can make your app easier to uninstall.

Comment: Yes Thanks but for the script i will need a https based script , So can i get any https server free for my opensource js files